# NightmareJS doesn't open a browser

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I'm currently making an electron app, and I've included Nightmare in the project.

```
  var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

  nightmare
  .goto('http://yahoo.com')
  .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
  .click('.searchsubmit').then(nightmare.show())
```

Thats the code that I'd like to see open a browser window, visit yahoo.com.

How come it's still headless when I put show:true?

Terminal:

```
$ DEBUG=nightmare* electron .
  nightmare queuing process start +0ms
  nightmare queueing action "goto" for http://yahoo.com +3ms
  nightmare queueing action "type" +2ms
  nightmare queueing action "click" +0ms
  nightmare running +0ms
```

I also changed my code which includes the whole snippet:

```
ipc.on('launchBrowser', function(event, data){
  var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

  nightmare
  .goto('http://yahoo.com')
  .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
  .click('.searchsubmit').then(() => {  });
});
```

Is it not working as expected because I'm not explicitly using node.js, but rather electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can call a function with () inside a "then" if you're not receiving its value

Maybe it is throwing some kind of error, even though you don't need  `nightmare.show()` since you set the property when creating the instance

Either change for something like this:

```
  var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

  nightmare
  .goto('http://yahoo.com')
  .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
  .click('.searchsubmit').then(nightmare.show)
```

or this:

```
  var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

  nightmare
  .goto('http://yahoo.com')
  .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
  .click('.searchsubmit').then(() => { nightmare.show(); });
```

or remove `nightmare.show()` entirely

```
  var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

  nightmare
  .goto('http://yahoo.com')
  .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
  .click('.searchsubmit').then(() => { //Something cool });
```

Comment: Hmm, even when I remove it, it still won't render the browser. Edited main post.